# La Clojure - What key is 'Meta' bound to on Windows environment?

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea, la-clojure

In IntelliJ IDEA's La Clojure plugin, what key is 'Meta' bound to on Windows environment?

Here is a screenshot of where it occurs:

[image]

Comment: Also the slurp feature does not appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Meta" key in Windows. You will need to remap them. Also the slurp functionality works fine, but in Windows it has the same shortcut as "Toggle Bookmark 9" and for some strange reason Control+Shift+0 doesn't work, so again, just remap them.

```
(map vector (map <caret>map vector))
```

Invoke slurp backwards

```
(map (vector map <caret>map vector))
```

Comment: Anyone know how to remap the keys in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the (general) key mappings via: **File->Settings->Keymap**
Select your desired **Keymap** (default should work fine), apply and everything should work again like used to...