# IntelliJ IDE suddenly started showing "meta" based shortcuts in windows

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been since morning digging up all the jetbrains tutorial and googling, if any where I get to see a way or meaning of replacing ctrl as meta in my intelliJ IDEA IDE 12.x version, but surprisingly there is no shortcut or explanation found in my notice till time. Does any one of here know how do I interpret "Meta" keyboard shortcut in order to have my intelliJ shortcuts work. Please see the Screenshot below and guide, how do I interpret in windows?

setting keymap would help? and how can I do that if yes!

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated. I am working on Windows on Idea 12.1.4

Thanks!

Comment: Please check your Keymap setting: File -> Settings -> type "Keymap" to search Keymap setting. Possibly you are using Mac OS related key map.

Comment: @lhuang:can you provide an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>Meta</kbd> is NOT a typical Windows key. So possibly you are not using Windows key map. You can change current key map in this way: File -> Settings -> type "Keymap" to search Keymap setting -> change your key map setting.

From @fnl comment:
Meta isn't a key typically found on modern machines at all. It's a leftover from Sun's demise, at best. Apple's computers have Control, Option, and Command (aka. Apple Key), much like Window's machines have Control, Alternate, and the Windows Key. So in fact, it's like the Windows or Apple Key, but Meta is so important to some that you often get offered to "replace" the Option/Alt Key with Meta's functionality.

Comment: Is it possible to use this keymap at all? I usually work in OSX and would rather just use remember the one set of shortcuts, with something reasonable standing in as the "Meta" key. But I can't find any key that acts as "Meta" at all nor a way to configure it as something else?

Comment: @WiseOldDuck I don't know how. Would you please try if Windows key works as Meta?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11358376/315837 That answer to another question suggests there is no Meta at all on Windows (I tried Windows, Alt, etc. etc. myself and had no success). Which begs the question what possible use these profiles have on Windows?

Comment: Uh. [Meta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key) isn't a key typically found on modern machines at all. It's a leftover from Sun's demise, at best. Apple's computers have Control, Option, and Command (aka. Apple Key), much like Window's machines have Control, Alternate, and the Windows Key. So in fact, its like the Windows or Apple Key, but Meta is so important to some that you often get offered to "replace" the Option/Alt Key with Meta's functionality.

Comment: @fnl Thanks a lot for this. I thought Meta key was Command key.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue with Pycharm. To make it work in windows, you can go to PyCharm IDE-> File-> Setting->KeyMap and change KeyMaps options from Eclipse(MAC OS X) to Eclipse or Default or Visual Studio. So it will work like normal windows short cuts.